# Has anyone sysnthesized perfluorocubane (AKA octafluorocubane)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, halides

Up until now, there have been attempts at synthesizing octafluorocubane, shown below, but success has been elusive.

[image: C8F8 from https://www.science.org/do/10.1126/a9b6212c-ea5f-46c5-af6f-ef3d2d1893f0/full/octafluorocubane.png]

Has there been any success, and how might the symmetry and fluorine's electron affinity affect its properties?

Answer (score 22):

[*Caveat*: This is not so much a question-and-answer as a desire to share Derek Lowe's article in his inimitable style. Given enough down-votes, I'll delete both Q-&-A. But enjoy the synthesis summary, cited below!]

Yes! The synthesis of perfluorocubane (or octafluorocubane, if you prefer) [*has* been accomplished](https://www.science.org/doi/full/10.1126/science.abq0516), as described by [Derek Lowe](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/perfluorocubane-you-would-expect-weird), "[I]t is predicted to have the ability to hold a free electron in the middle of that cube (!) That's because of the C-F bond properties - all the electron density is being pulled towards the F atoms, so the center of the cube really has room for one to sit in there without running into a lot of interference... [T]here are eight sigma-star orbitals from those C-F bonds all pointing into the center of the cage and overlapping, and giving you effectively a stabilized vacant orbital there."

Get more details in [Lowe's article](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/perfluorocubane-you-would-expect-weird)!

Comment: "*Quantum Mechanics: A Hand-Waving Approach*" - I'd buy that book if Derek wrote it!

Comment: I'll upvote if you go into the [related HN comments section](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=32566743) and straighten-out some of those goofy comments :)

Comment: @ToddMinehardt, I'd upvote anyone who convinces Lowe to continue his series, *Things I Won't Work With*, or start another! They're great material for teaching, or just for personal edification and amusement.

Comment: I think the electron is trapped by the 8 positively charged carbons.

Comment: They should try dodecahedrane next!

Comment: BTW, realize that though octafluorocubane can trap an occasional electron, one could not produce a bulk sample where each molecule traps an electron due to the *total* Coulomb (electrostatic) repulsion. "If a pair of charges of 1 C each were 1 m apart, the force of repulsion between the two charges would be 9 billion newton's," from http://www.tecumseh.k12.oh.us/Downloads/Physics_12_23.pdf . Of course, if there's a similar molecule that can cage *protons*, one *could*, theoretically, mix the two "clathrates" to make it electrically neutral (if the charges don't unite to make hydrogen). ;-)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik one wild idea is to use an alkali metal as the electron source, complexing it with a cryptand, thus $\ce{[M(crypt)^+][C8F8^-]}$.